# I've lost administrator access and /var/db/.AppleSetupDone is read only

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra, administrator, single-user

I have lost administrator access  after trying to change my username in system preferences and restarting.

I have followed the directions by rebooting in Single user mode, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and typing the following commands:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy    

/sbin/mount -uw /  

rm /var/db/.applesetupdone
```

It then asks if I want to override `rm /var/db/.applesetupdone` and if I then type "YES" it says that it is a read only file and nothing happens.

I have also tried typing `rm /var/db/.applesetupdone` in terminal and again it asks me if I want to override, and again answering YES I get the reply Permission denied:

```
override r--------  root/wheel for /var/db/.applesetupdone? YES

rm: /var/db/.applesetupdone: Permission denied
```

I am using MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.4

**How do I remove applesetupdone or get administrator privileges back?**

Answer (score 2):

You can run the command as superuser [(explanation on wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser)

Either run

```
sudo rm /var/db/.applesetupdone
```

or

```
su
```

to log in as super user and then regularly run the commands.

Comment: downvotes without commenting what the issue is are barely helpful

Answer (score 1):

You may have to boot the system in recovery mode

1. Command+ R. Release the keys when the Apple logo and a progress bar appear.
2. select Disk Utility and continue.
3. Select your startup disk in the pane to the left
4. If its not mounted (greyed ) then  mount using mount button  username and enter your password, if requested .
5. Quit Disk Utility.
6. macOS utility window will appear.
7. Go to top menu bar (Apple logo)
8. Click  on Utilities.
9. Start Terminal from the drop-down menu (if not starts click again ).
10. Enter the following command,
11. Substitute "startup disk" with the actual name of your startup disk.
12. rm '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/var/db/.AppleSetupDone'
13. ls -a Volumes/Macintosh HD/var/db/  to see if the -AppleSetupDone exists
14. Restart your Mac and it will launch Setup Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

To Restore a  Macbook Pro with OSX 1068:

- Boot holding down: CMD+S
- /sbin/mount -uw /
- rm /var/db/.applesetupdone
- Override ...? Y
- type reboot
- Done!
- If this procedure does not work on the first time around, simply repeat it once more.
- Hope this helps others too!

LAO