# Can I delete my own account?

Tags: mac, accounts

I wanted to know if I could delete my own user in my mac, I have administrator permissions. Can I only delete other users or can I delete my own account too?
(EDIT : i don't use the Mac anymore so I want to delete my own account, there is an other admin account (the Mac owner). It would save a lot of place in my Mac)

Comment: Just asking the other user to remove your account might be the easiest way, actually.

Comment: cant come home because of coronavirus

Comment: Check out the answers to the question linked on top of yours here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new account with administrator permissions. Log out of your account. Log into the new one. Delete your account.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321546/ive-lost-administrator-access-and-var-db-applesetupdone-is-read-only and http://www.theinstructional.com/guides/how-to-re-run-the-os-x-setup-assistant and

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310308/delete-a-standard-user-from-mac-os